# What does "I'm jacked" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

In [this film clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ5VfKSYvSk) one of the characters says "I'm jacked... I'm jacked to the tits!!!" - what does this mean in this context and other contexts?

Comment: It means excited, full of energy, ready to do something; same as "jacked up." It can be completely natural (an adrenaline rush) or drug-fueled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context "jacked" is a slang term similar to "high", meaning "under the influence of a powerful (usually illegal) drug.  If I had to guess at its origin, I imagine it's a picturesque metaphor of your body plugged into an electrical socket, and therefore "full of energy" or "lit up".  So it's most often used to refer to the use of drugs that make you feel especially powerful or energetic (like cocaine or perhaps steroids).

"Jacked to the tits," is a colorful metaphor that simply means "very high".  In this film clip I don't know if the character is *actually* under the influence of a drug, but he *feels* as if he is high -- he's almost uncontrollably excited.

You should be careful not to confuse this with other slang terms that use "jacked".  In some dialects, "jacked" or "jacked up" means "to have some injury or incapacity".  For example, I could say something like:

> I woke up this morning and my neck was *jacked up* (my neck hurts).  I must have slept weird.
>
> She ran her car off of the road and her body was *jacked* for months after.

Of course, you can use both, for fun:

> He was totally *jacked* last night but after he came down he was *jacked up* all the next day.

There are other slang uses of "jacked".  In some contexts it can mean "stolen" (as an abbreviation of "hijacked"):

> Dude!  My car got *jacked* last night!

Or as previously mentioned, as the verb meaning "to plug into an electrical outlet" (based on the noun "**jack**: a female fitting in an electric circuit used with a plug to make a connection with another circuit"):

> Hey could you *jack* my guitar into the amp?

It's a fun word.  Remember, though -- slang isn't universal.  I don't know if these meanings will translate anywhere English is spoken.  Also it's constantly evolving, so terms can take on a different nuance over time.

[Here is a list of various other definitions for "jack"](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/jack), although even this is not complete

Comment: AmE speaker here: I've never heard "jacked up" to mean "hurt" or "ruined," but I'm pretty old so I may be out of touch. Also, one can be jacked up without using illegal drugs -- the body naturally produces adrenaline. Otherwise, this is an excellent answer!

Comment: @MarkHubbard I'm old too so it's likely localized.  Hence my warning about slang, unless you don't mind funny looks.  :)

Comment: A female Australian grad student who served as a Resident Advisor in the university dormitories came to breakfast looking unusually tired one morning and said, "I got knocked up at 3:00 a.m.," and then wondered why we all laughed. When we asked her if she was going to the football game to "root for the team," she turned bright red. Ah, the vagaries of English slang. :-)

Comment: Another slang meaning of "jacked" is "muscular", by the way.

Comment: FWIW, I first heard "jacked up" to mean "messed up" about twenty years ago, in urban Michigan.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I can confirm the usage.  AmE speaker in the Northeast.

Comment: I've also heard "jacked" to mean "messed up", but without the adverbial "up". As in, "His body was jacked from all the heroin."

Comment: @MarkHubbard I've often heard 'jacked up' used as a synonym of 'f%cked up' and not in the drunk or drugged sense.  I think it might be the first way I heard it used outside of car maintenance.   I think 12-15 years ago.  I also know of a kids rhyme with the phrase "mess with me and I'll jack you up"

Comment: Definitely.  My answer isn't a comprehensive list of all the ways "jack" is used in (AmE) slang, and even [this page](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/jack) isn't complete.  As I said, it's a fun word.

Comment: @JimmyJames, Lumberjack and Andrew: Interesting, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in the big short I believe I'm jacked means I am extremely leveraged in terms of the commissions he has to pay on his investments because they were rated far more highly than they were valued in reality he asked Mark Baum if he could feel that and Mark said no. it's not about the in high

Comment: Not about being high

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).